# ElasticSearch NEST Search

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm encountering an unexpected error when I try to perform a search on an ElasticSearch instance. I'm following the documentation here (http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/quick-start.html) verbatim, but I"m getting the error "Error 1 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Nest.SearchDescriptor' because it is not a delegate type." The first s of "s => s" is being highlighted. Maybe it's just a C# syntax issue. Any ideas?

```
var searchResults = client.Search<Person>(s=>s
      .From(0)
      .Size(10)
      .Query(q=>q
     .Term(p=>p.Firstname, "martijn")
    )
 );
```

Comment: Do you by chance have another variable named `s` in the same scope?

Comment: No, I already checked that

Comment: Sc0rpio which version of NEST are you using and what version of .NET i just followed the quick start without problems.

Comment: I'm running NEST 1.0.0 and .NET 4.5.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Your problem is probably about character case. If you add FirstName field to Person object, then you need to write it as FirstName not Firstname, inside the lambda expression.

Answer (score -1):

In Elasticsearch, filtering and querying are crucial for retrieving specific data sets. The provided solution demonstrates how to effectively filter search results based on a particular property in an index, in this case, Firstname.

Detailed Explanation of the Code:
The initial code snippet uses a combination of Bool and Filter within a Term query. Here's a breakdown:

Bool: This is used for combining multiple filter criteria.
Filter: Filters contribute to the query but do not influence the score. This is useful for filtering by exact matches.
Term: The Term query is utilized for exact value matching.
Here, it's used to match the Firstname field with the value "martijn".

```
var searchResults = client.Search<Person>(s => s
.From(0)
.Size(10)
.Query(q => q
    .Bool(b => b
        .Filter(bf => bf
            .Term(t => t.Field(f => f.Firstname).Value("martijn"))
        )));
```

Comparison with Alternative Approaches:
The alternative solution uses the Match query. Unlike Term, which is for exact matches, Match is better suited for full-text search and can handle text analysis. This makes it more flexible for partial matches or text fields.

```
var searchResults = client.Search<Person>(s => s
.From(0)
.Size(10)
.Query(q => q
    .Match(m => m
        .Field(p => p.Firstname)
        .Query("martijn")
    ));
```

Pros and Cons:
Term: Best for exact, unanalyzed matches. Fast but less flexible.
Match: More versatile for text search, handles analysis, but slightly slower due to processing.

Real-world Application Example:
Imagine an application where you need to find user profiles based on exact usernames. Term would be ideal here. Conversely, for a search feature within a blog platform, Match would be more suitable to handle various text inputs.

For more details on the differences and use-cases for Bool, Filter, and Term queries, refer to the Elasticsearch official documentation.

Best Practices and Tips:
When constructing queries:
Ensure fields used in Term queries are not analyzed.
Use Match for fields that require text analysis.
Monitor query performance, especially with complex Bool queries.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.17/bool-queries.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).